# django.db.models ImageField save Image as Base64

Tags: django, image, base64, python-imaging-library, imagefield

I'm actually new to Django. Let's say I have this model as a class

```
class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  ...
  profile_photo = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='photos/profile-picture', blank=True)

  objects = UserAccountManager()
  def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I want to save the `profile_photo` attribute as a base64 file (instead of file path). How do I do that?

Context : In my client side (front-end), I can't render the image by getting its file path. So I want to save the image as base64 string in the DB instead of actual image path so that it will be easier to render in the front end

Comment: Did you try to render image in the template like this <img src=" media/photos/profile-picture/image.jpg" >  You should be rendering the image by getting its file path. If not you probably didn't specify MEDIA_URL in settings.py. You can check it out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: No, I don't use the template from django HTML template. I use another framework (react) for templating so i can't access that

Answer (score 0):

ImageField has "url" property. It's will combine with MEDIA_URL in the project's setting.

Comment: The thing here, I use my front end running on different port (for client side rendering) so i can't access the url property of imagefield